# std::tuple for non-copyable and non-movable object

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I have a class with copy & move ctor deleted.

```
struct A
{
    A(int a):data(a){}
    ~A(){ std::cout << "~A()" << this << " : " << data << std::endl; }

    A(A const &obj) = delete;
    A(A &&obj) = delete;

    friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & out , A const & obj);

    int data;
};
```

And I want to create a tuple with objects of this class. But the following does not compile:

```
auto p = std::tuple<A,A>(A{10},A{20});
```

On the other hand, the following *does* compile, but gives a surprising output.

```
int main() {
    auto q = std::tuple<A&&,A&&>(A{100},A{200});
    std::cout << "q created\n";
}
```

Output

```
~A()0x22fe10 : 100
~A()0x22fe30 : 200
q created
```

It means that dtor for objects is called as soon as tuple construction line ends. So, what is significance of a tuple of destroyed objects?

Comment: `std::tuple<A&&,A&&>(A{100},A{200});` is a tuple of dangling references. I think `std::tuple<A,A> p(100, 200);` should work instead

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki It does not compile on clang or g++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fe2146b7881e241

Comment: @NathanOliver it does, either use `libc++` or a newer `libstdc++`

Comment: don't help the compiler: `std::forward_as_tuple(A{100}, A{200})`

Comment: @TemplateRex that would still require a move-/copy-constructor, or create a tuple of dangling references, wouldn't it?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki yes, no life-time extension from fwd_tup

Comment: Yeah... std::forward_as_tuple(A{100}, A{200}) is also a tuple of dangling objects..

Comment: I think that you can do that with a pair and `std::piecewise_construct`. AFAIK `tuple` does not have a constructor that takes a `std::piecewise_construct_t`.

Comment: It works like Piotr says, check here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lEjHXqI4FtKgoomN

Comment: Yep it happens to work in this specific case because `int` is implicitly converible to `A`. That will not work in the general case.

Comment: I am uncertain why `std::tuple<A,A> x = std::make_tuple(3,99);` does not work.

Comment: @Yakk That constructor would be `explicit` because `int const&` is not convertible to `A`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is bad:

```
auto q = std::tuple<A&&,A&&>(A{100},A{200});
```

you are constructing a `tuple` of rvalue references to temporaries that get destroyed at the end of the expression, so you're left with dangling references.

The correct statement would be:

```
std::tuple<A, A> q(100, 200);
```

---

However, until quite recently, the above was not supported by the standard. In N4296, the wording around the relevant constructor for `tuple` is [tuple.cnstr]:

> ```
> template <class... UTypes>
>   constexpr explicit tuple(UTypes&&... u);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: `sizeof...(Types) == sizeof...(UTypes)`. `is_constructible<Ti, Ui&&>::value` is true
>   for all `i`.
>   *Effects*: Initializes the elements in the tuple with the corresponding value in `std::forward<UTypes>(u)`.
>   *Remark*: This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution **unless each type in `UTypes` is
>   implicitly convertible to its corresponding type in `Types`**.

So, this constructor was not participating in overload resolution because `int` is not implicitly convertible to `A`. This has been resolved by the adoption of [Improving `pair` and `tuple`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html), which addressed precisely your use-case:

```
struct D { D(int); D(const D&) = delete; };    
std::tuple<D> td(12); // Error
```

The new wording for this constructor is, from N4527:

> *Remarks*: This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution **unless `sizeof...(Types) >= 1` and `is_constructible<Ti, Ui&&>::value` is true for all `i`**. The constructor is explicit if and only
>   if `is_convertible<Ui&&, Ti>::value` is `false` for at least one *i*.

And `is_constructible<A, int&&>::value` is true.

To present the difference another way, here is an extremely stripped down tuple implementation:

```
struct D { D(int ) {} D(const D& ) = delete; };

template <typename T>
struct Tuple {
    Tuple(const T& t)
    : T(t)
    { }

    template <typename U,
#ifdef USE_OLD_RULES
              typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>
#else
              typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, U&&>::value>
#endif
              >
    Tuple(U&& u)
    : t(std::forward<U>(u))
    { }

    T t;
};

int main()
{
    Tuple<D> t(12);
}
```

If `USE_OLD_RULES` is defined, the first constructor is the only viable constructor and hence the code will not compile since `D` is noncopyable. Otherwise, the second constructor is the best viable candidate and that one is well-formed.

---

The adoption was recent enough that neither gcc 5.2 nor clang 3.6 actually will compile this example yet. So you will either need a newer compiler than that (gcc 6.0 works) or come up with a different design.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that `std::tuple<D> td = std::make_tuple(12);` should also work?

Comment: isn't the `template <class... UTypes> explicit tuple(UTypes&&... args);` constructor available in C++11 ?

Comment: @Yakk No, that constructor is `explicit`. But `std::tuple<D> td{std::make_tuple(12)}` also wouldn't work before the adoption of that paper.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki See update for explanation of why it wasn't called.

Comment: *"this constructor was not participating in overload resolution because int is not implicitly convertible to `A` "* doesn't refer to anything in the question, as the question doesn't use any implicit conversion anywhere. Note that it uses `std::tuple<A&&,A&&>(A{100},A{200})` as opposed to `std::tuple<A&&,A&&>(100,200);` So it is an irrelevant point, so is the entire para which discusses the quote from N4296.

Comment: @Nawaz Did you actually read my answer? I know what the question uses - I talked about why that's wrong, talked about the right way to construct it, and then spend most of the time talking about why the *right* way to construct it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does this mean if A::A(int a) were made explicit, there'd be no way to construct a std::tuple<A, A> or std::pair<A, A>?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you explicitly asked for a tuple of rvalue references, and a rvalue reference is not that far from a pointer.

So `auto q = std::tuple<A&&,A&&>(A{100},A{200});` creates two A objects, takes (rvalue) references to them, build the tuple with the references... and destroys the temporary objects, leaving you with two dangling references

Even if it is said to be more secure than good old C and its dangling pointers, C++ still allows programmer to write wrong programs.

Anyway, the following would make sense (note usage of A& and not A&&):

```
int main() {
    A a(100), b(100); // Ok, a and b will leave as long as main
    auto q = tuple<A&, A&>(a, b);  // ok, q contains references to a and b
    ...
    return 0; // Ok, q, a and b will be destroyed
}
```