# Can I make std::pair of two std::ostream-s?

Tags: c++, c++17, ostream, std-pair

I'd like to make a pair containing two `std::ostream` object. I need this so that I can pass a single object to various functions instead of two `std::ostream` objects. I was hoping I could do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qsfKqr):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    std::ostream output( std::cout.rdbuf());
    std::ostream error(std::cout.rdbuf());

    using Logger = std::pair< std::ostream, std::ostream >;
    Logger logger = std::make_pair( output, error );

  return 0;
}
```

But I get a compiler error that there isn't a matching constructor for `pair<std::basic_ostream<char>, std::basic_ostream<char> >`

Comment: FYI: in case you don't want a tuple-of-references (as some answers suggest) but a tuple-of-objects (as original question states) see [putting a non-copiable into a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32763826/717732)

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to be aware of the [no-op output stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11826666/4641116).

Comment: I was in inspired by your question to use ANSI escape sequences to make the `output` stream black text on white (class NormalBuffer : public std::streambuf), and the `error` stream white text on red (class RedBuffer : public std::streambuf).  Useful for output to a terminal; not very useful redirecting to an output file.   Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you’re having is that `ostream` can’t be copied.
The solution is to use a pair of references:

```
using Logger = std::pair<std::ostream &, std::ostream &>;
Logger logger { output, error };
```

Comment: Of course. I didn't want to copy them anyway. I wanted a reference, but couldn't make it work. You've done however.

Comment: Dani - can't be copied doesn't mean it can't be put into a tuple. FYI: [putting a non-copiable into a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32763826/717732) - but yeah, I agree that keeping output/error obejcts elsewhere and passing references to output/error will probably make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying, which is not supported for streams, you can make pair of references to them

```
auto logger{::std::tie(output, error)};
```

Comment: Is it a tuple or a pair?

Comment: @Dani a pair is a tuple of 2 items.

Comment: Although they can be usually converted, a pair is not a tuple of two elements. For example, `pair<int,int> *a = new tuple(1, 1);` will fail to compile.